# Confluence / JIRA :: What is a Filter Result Gadget?

Tags: jira, confluence, agile, jira-agile, agile-project-management

I would like to create an Eisenhower Matrix in Confluence / JIRA.

I taught found a practical [solution on the ATLASSIAN Community](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/Eisenhower-chart-in-JIRA/qaq-p/841834) :

[image]

but unfortunately when I put it in place I cannot find a `Filter Result Gadget` in Confluence.

Is anyone aware of how to filter a list of tickets inside a table in Confluence?

Comment: https://confluence.atlassian.com/jira064/adding-the-filter-results-gadget-720416922.html

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: @xsorifc28, thank you, I think it might be the solution but I'm stuck at the step 1: `Go to your JIRA dashboard and click Add Gadget.` The Dashboard is a big sea, where the hack is  `Add Gadget`? Can you provide a screenshot, please?

Comment: If you click the "dashboard" link in step 1, that page shows a screenshot. In that screenshot, "add gadget" is on the top right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this guide to accomplish this.

https://confluence.atlassian.com/jira064/adding-the-filter-results-gadget-720416922.html

> The Dashboard is a big sea, where the hack is Add Gadget? Can you provide a screenshot, please?

The "add gadget" button:

[image: add gadget button location]